# Less redundant if statement?

Tags: python

```
    @functools.cached_property
    def dependencies(self):
        """
        Get a list of dependencies.
        """
        number_of_dependencies = int.from_bytes(
            self.__data[
                self.__dependency_table_offset : self.__dependency_table_offset + 4
            ],
            byteorder="big",
            signed=True,
        )
        dependencies = self.__data[self.__dependency_table_offset :]
        dependency_list = []
        offset = 0x4
        guid, sha1_hash = helpers.get_resource_descriptor(self.__head_revision)
        for i in range(number_of_dependencies):
            if dependencies[offset:][0] == sha1_hash:
                dependency_list.append(
                    (
                        "h"
                        + str(
                            int.from_bytes(
                                dependencies[offset + 0x1 : offset + 0x15],
                                byteorder="big",
                                signed=True,
                            )
                        ),
                        int.from_bytes(
                            dependencies[offset + 0x15 : offset + 0x19],
                            byteorder="big",
                            signed=True,
                        ),
                    )
                )
                offset += 0x19
            elif dependencies[offset:][0] == guid:
                dependency_list.append(
                    (
                        "g"
                        + str(
                            int.from_bytes(
                                dependencies[offset + 0x1 : offset + 0x5],
                                byteorder="big",
                                signed=True,
                            )
                        ),
                        int.from_bytes(
                            dependencies[offset + 0x5 : offset + 0x9],
                            byteorder="big",
                            signed=True,
                        ),
                    )
                )
                offset += 0x9
        return dependency_list
```

I'm trying to make my code more readable and compact, and I'm wondering if theres a way to instead when appending to dependencies_list, only do one append based on whether it's a hash or guid instead of an if/elif statement. Is there a way to reduce the amount of code? It seems a bit bloated and therefore less readable. If anyone has any suggestions for reducing something like this that would be greatly appreciated. Also, I'm using Python 3.8, so I can't use match case.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this might be a better fit for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). However, one idea is to factor out just the bits that are different, changing your loop to something like the following:

```py
for i in range(num_dependencies):
    dep_id = dependencies[offset:][0]
    if dep_id == sha1_hash:
        code = 'h'
        n1 = dependencies[offset + 0x1 : offset + 0x15]
        n2 = dependencies[offset + 0x15 : offset + 0x19]
        inc = 0x19
    elif dep_id == guid:
        code = 'g'
        n1 = dependencies[offset + 0x1 : offset + 0x5]
        n2 = dependencies[offset + 0x5 : offset + 0x9]
        inc = 0x9
    else:
        continue
    dependency_list.append((
        code + str(int.from_bytes(n1, byteorder="big", signed=True)),
        int.from_bytes(n2, byteorder="big", signed=True),
    ))
    offset += inc
```

That also has the effect of shortening the amount of work you're doing in one statement, reducing the amount of wrapped lines and the verbosity that results in.

In addition, this code looks like a good candidate for [`struct.unpack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#struct.unpack) -- it may be a lot more compact using that library.

Comment: Thanks, out of curiosity, how would struct.unpack be implemented for something like this? I'm not sure if it's possible since the dep_id is unknown, meaning the byte stream length can range from anything and doesn't contain the same type. Also, since one of the types is a SHA-1 hash, I don't think this is possible as it has a length of 20.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right that the 20-byte SHA can't be decoded to an int with `struct.unpack`. You could us `struct.unpack` for the others, but yeah, then it'd be inconsistent, so probably best to avoid.

Comment: One other thing: shorter variable names can make code like this easier to read (partly because it avoids the really long lines). For example, `num_deps` is very clear in this context vs `number_of_dependencies`, `_deps_offset` vs `__dependency_table_offset`. And for clarity, I'd probably replace `dependencies` with `dep_data` and `dependency_list` with `deps` (usually a `_list` type suffix is a mild code smell).